# How do i define a postgis polygon based on a great circle line

Tags: gis, postgis

I wish to use PostGIS to select all the points within a polygon, but this question is about defining the actual polygon.

I'm looking to define a polygon that is based on a great circle, specified by two points on the earths surface defined by latitude and longitude coordinates. The polygon that I'm after should be defined by a width left and right of the the center line (the center line being the line made by the great circle)

The resulting shape would be a long curved rectangular shape.

The purpose being to select all the points within x distance of the great circle line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about the kind of data you are dealing with, if you use a equidistant projection you could use something as simple as this:

```
ST_DWithIn(ST_MakeLine(point1, point2),distanceInSRIDunits)
```

There is an old discussion in the [postgis mail list](http://postgis.refractions.net/pipermail/postgis-users/2008-February/018620.html) that will be useful to you.